# Access- Vb- updating one table based on other table's value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Access DB with vb. 
I want to update the values of one table base on other tables values

for example
Table A has columns a1, a2, a3,.....
Table B has columns b1,b2,b3.......

if a1 and b1 are he ID numbers, for each matching ID in table B, the value of B3 has to be updated in a3 as well

If first value of b1 is 1234, then search for 1234 in tableA , the update tha a3 position of that particular row with b3 value.

Please let me know how to move on with this.

Comment: Use the query design window. Add both tables, join on the id using drag and drop. Alternatively, use the Access query wizards.

Comment: Thanks for the response..but I'm sorry Remou. I'm totally new. I can find the query design and make a join with the ids. after this how do I update one table based on other table's value.

Comment: Start here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/select-data-by-using-a-query-HA010285100.aspx

Comment: here is another problem. I have created an update query on one table based on value from the other table.UPDATE KeyTable090808 SET KeyTable090808.DEPT = (SELECT pplsft_IDandDEPT.pplsft_Dept_Name FROM pplsft_IDandDEPT WHERE pplsft_IDandDEPT.pplsft_UTDID = KeyTable090808.Employee_ID);

Comment: In this case, the select retrieves more than 1 row! so the update is not being done! I want it to be done one by one. for every matching id, the corresponding department should be updated in Access.. Are there an ways of passing the parameter(EmployeeID) one by one, or are there any other ways of implementing the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It may not work if you do not have suitable indexes.

```
UPDATE KeyTable090808 
INNER JOIN pplsft_IDandDEPT 
ON KeyTable090808.Employee_ID = pplsft_IDandDEPT.pplsft_UTDID
SET KeyTable090808.DEPT = pplsft_IDandDEPT.pplsft_Dept_Name
```